# MySQL: Updating a left-joined view, where right table has no matching data

Tags: mysql

I'm curious to know if this is actually possible...

In this simplified example, I have:

```
Table_A:           Table_B:

+------+--------+  +------+--------+
| id   | data_1 |  | id   | data_2 |
+------+--------+  +------+--------+
| 1    | Hello  |  | 1    | There  |
+------+--------+  +------+--------+
| 2    | Hi     |
+------+--------+
```

A MySQL View (`CREATE VIEW...`) called `tables` is:

```
SELECT table_a.id AS id, 
 table_a.data_1 AS data_1, 
 table_b.data_2 AS data_2
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id=table_b.id
```

So, a simple `SELECT * FROM tables` will return:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| id   | data_1 | data_2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| 1    | Hello  | There  |
+------+--------+--------+
| 2    | Hi     | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+
```

An update to existing data is fine. Ie., `UPDATE tables SET data_2='World' WHERE id=1` completes and the result for id 1 would be:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| id   | data_1 | data_2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| 1    | Hello  | World  |
+------+--------+--------+
```

But what about using an `UPDATE` statement on the right table (`table_b`) if it does not have any data matching the id? Using the same example as earlier, `UPDATE tables SET data_2='John' WHERE id=2` will result in 0 Rows matched (and therefore, `tables` will still return `NULL` instead of `John` in the `data_2` field).

```
+------+--------+--------+
| id   | data_1 | data_2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| 2    | Hi     | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Is there a way to make this work on the `tables` view, without having to touch the `table_b` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do what you're suggesting, it's best to maintain a foreign key in table_b even if there isn't a value for data_2. As answered already it will take two statements. First you'd have to backfill table_b with missing keys from table_a. Something like this should work.

```
INSERT INTO table_b(id)
SELECT table_a.id, table_b.id
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE table_b.id is null;
```

Once you've completed the backfill, then your original update statement would work.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an insert, not an update, since no row exists in table_b with id=2. You could do it with two separate statements, one to do the update (with an inner join), and another to do the insert. I doubt it's possible in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, since there is no row to `UPDATE`.

You want an `INSERT` here, that's why you need to `INSERT` a row into `table_b` directly.

If your `table_b.id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE KEY`, you can do the following:

```
INSERT
INTO    table_b (id, data2)
VALUES  (2, 'There')
```

, which will `UPDATE` the corresponding row if `id = 2` already exists in the table, or `INSERT` it if it doesn't.